# FacesTopLevelMultiple could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

Having an issue with a face detection program, using the Visual Recognition API that IBM Watson provides. I wrote a program based on a tutorial I found, but I'm getting an error that's preventing it from running. The error is as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBN0p.png

Here is the code that I'm running for face detection:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.VisualRecognition.v3;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Connection;


public class FaceDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text dataOutput;
    private VisualRecognition _visualRecognition;
    private string path = "C:\\Users\\Alberto\\Desktop\\Alberto.jpg";

    public string _serviceUrl;
    public string _iamApikey;

    void Start() {
        LogSystem.InstallDefaultReactors();
        Runnable.Run(CreateService());
    }

    private IEnumerator CreateService() {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_iamApikey)) {
            throw new WatsonException("Please provide IAM ApiKey for the service.");
        }

        Credentials credentials = null;

        TokenOptions tokenOptions = new TokenOptions() {
            IamApiKey = _iamApikey
        };

        credentials = new Credentials(tokenOptions, _serviceUrl);

        //wait for token
        while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())
            yield return null;

        //create credentials
        _visualRecognition = new VisualRecognition(credentials);
        _visualRecognition.VersionDate = "2019-02-26";
    }

    public void DetectFaces(string path) {
        //classify using image url
        // if (!_visualRecognition.DetectFaces(picURL, OnDetectFaces, OnFail))
        //     Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition.DetectFaces()", "Detect faces failed!");

        //classify using image path
        if(!_visualRecognition.DetectFaces(OnDetectFaces, OnFail, path)) {
            Debug.Log("ExampleVisualRecognition.DetectFaces()", "Detect faces failed!");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Calling Watson");
            dataOutput.text = "";
        }
    }

    private void OnDetectFaces(FacesTopLevelMultiple multipleImages, Dictionary<string, object> customData) {
        var data = multipleImages.images[0].faces[0];
        dataOutput.text = "Age : " + data.age.min + "-" + data.age.max + " PROBABILITY: " + data.age.score + "\n";
        "Gender: " + data.gender.gender + " PROBABILITY: " + data.gender.score + "\n";
        Debug.Log("ExampleVisualRecognition.OnDetectFaces(): Detect faces result: " + customData["json"].ToString());
    }

    private void OnFail(RESTConnector.Error error, Dictionary<string, object> customData) {
        Debug.LogError("ExampleVisualRecognition.OnFail(): Error received: " + error.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the script that enables the webcam to track my face:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.VisualRecognition.v3;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities;

public class CameraRender : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image overlay;
    public FaceDetector fd;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        WebCamTexture backCam = new WebCamTexture();
        backCam.Play();
        overlay.material.mainTexture = backCam;
    }

    public void CaptureImage() {
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("screenshot.png");
        fd.DetectFaces(application.persistentDataPath + "/screenshot.png");

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            CaptureImage();
        }
    }
```

}

I hope this helps figure out what the issue is. FacesTopLevelMultiple is used near the bottom of the FaceDetector script.

Comment: Which version of Unity and the Watson SDK are you using?

Comment: The Watson SDK is the latest version on the Github. Unity is in 2018.3.0f2

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detectFaces callback seems to be outdated (probably from a tutorial that needs to be updated). The method signature should be

```cs
OnDetectFaces(DetectedFaces multipleImages, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
```

You should be able to find the faces using

```cs
private void OnDetectFaces(DetectedFaces multipleImages, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleFaceDetection", "First face age: {0}", multipleImages.images[0].faces[0].age);
    Log.Debug("ExampleFaceDetection", "First face gender: {0}", multipleImages.images[0].faces[0].gender);
}
```

Comment: I tried the program with the new code but it's throwing more errors now.
https://imgur.com/a/ZeZ9pZU

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/issues/525). It looks like this particular overload of DetectFaces has `acceptLanugage` as required when it should be optional. I will fix this in the SDK but until then please add `en` as a parameter to your DetectFaces call. `if(!_visualRecognition.DetectFaces(OnDetectFaces, OnFail, path, "en"))`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, that seems to have resolved almost all of the errors. Last thing, and this may be something I have to figure out for myself, I'm getting an error stating:

Assets\FaceDetector.cs(54,65): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'UnityEngine.Object'

It's in reference to the DetectFaces call. Might have to do with my path.

Comment: Change `Debug.Log("ExampleVisualRecognition.DetectFaces()", "Detect faces failed!");` to `Debug.Log("ExampleVisualRecognition.DetectFaces(), Detect faces failed!");` (single string). Also please mark this as the answer if it's working.

Comment: The [PR](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/pull/526) has been merged and will be released after passing CI.

Comment: I know I marked it as correct, because it does run. However, I'm having an issue where I'm not getting any output. It's possible I'm misunderstanding how to console log, but the two Log.Debugs from the solution above don't output to anything. The hope was to output them to the Text that is inside the Canvas, and display them on screen, but just a simple output to the console would be fine too.

Comment: For example, the Debug.Log("Calling Watson"); never outputs anything, despite it being set to output if faces are detected (or output an error message if it's not).